# Fill with User Input Reactive Dataframe with Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, shiny

For a simple app in Shiny, I want to take user input, perform simple arithmetic operations on it and store the results in a dataframe with the overall objective to plot it then by comparing the results from the first column with the second column for x = 1:60.

Being new to Shiny, I struggle in dealing with the reactive part within a loop which is why my code looks currently like a simple method to perform the operation in R and ostensibly does not work.

Any hint to store reactive values in the dataframe would be appreciated.

In a simplified form, my code looks like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 numericInput("In1", "Input 1", 60),
 numericInput("In2", "Input 2", 100),
 numericInput("In3", "Input 3", 100)

mainPanel(plotOutput("plot))
)
_______
server <- function(input, output) {

data1 <- reactive({

data1 <- data.frame(x = 0, y = 1:60)

data1[1, 1] = (input$In1 * 4 * 12)/input$In3
data1[1, 2] = (input$In2 * 4 * 12)/input$In3

for (i in 2:60) {
data1[i,1] = (input$In1 * 4 * 12)/input$In3) + data1[i-1]
data1[i,2] = (input$In2 * 4 * 12)/input$In3) + data1[i-1]
}})

output$plot <- renderPlot({...})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the app as :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("In1", "Input 1", 60),
  numericInput("In2", "Input 2", 100),
  numericInput("In3", "Input 3", 100),
  
  mainPanel(tableOutput("data"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

data1 <- reactive({

data1 <- data.frame(x = 0, y = 1:60)

data1[1, 1] = (input$In1 * 4 * 12)/input$In3
data1[1, 2] = (input$In2 * 4 * 12)/input$In3

for (i in 2:60) {
data1[i,1] = ((input$In1 * 4 * 12)/input$In3) + data1[i-1, 1]
data1[i,2] = ((input$In2 * 4 * 12)/input$In3) + data1[i-1, 2]
}
return(data1)
})

#output$plot <- renderPlot({...})
output$data <- renderTable({data1()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I haven't included any plot code but instead displayed the dataframe but you can also include the plot output the way you want.